# Excel Pivot table count between

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I have a problem creating a pivot table/chart with between date function.
I would like to know the total count of projects that are active between two dates. A Chart with on the x-axis week 1 - week 52 is what i'm trying to create.

**Example Chart**

20
10
 
5
 
0
 

        week 1    week 2   week 3 .....

**My columns:**

Project ID | START WEEK NUMBER| END WEEK NUMBER

**What have I already done?**

Adding helper columns 1 till 52 with the following function: 

   `=IF(AH$1=MEDIAN($AB10;$AD10);1;IF(AH$1=$AB10;1;IF(AH$1=$AD10;1;"")))`

This will show a 1 when the column week header is equal or between date start week and end week. But with this I am still not able to create a chart with the weeks on the x-axis and the total count of that week.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new sheet and in Column A put your weeks 1-52 down.  In column B use this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet6!$B$2:$B$18,"<="&A2,Sheet6!$C$2:$C$18,">="&A2)
```

1. Sheet6! Needs to be replaced with the name of your Sheet, e.g. Projects!
2. Column B range needs to be the entire range of your start week
3. Column C range needs to be the entire range of your end week
4. B and C dimensions need to match.

Comment: Thanks this works for a single view. But the reason why I choose a Pivot table is that I have more columns where I would like to filter from e.g. team, year etc.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do what you want with a pivot table.  You can use list dropdowns and more criteria in your countifs to add filters to the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a pivot table, try rearranging your source data as shown:

[image]

Comment: That is not possible. I got a dump from a database. And it means i would get 40.000+ rows since projects can be like 10 weeks (and I have 5000 projects).